# Efficiency & speedup of parallel vs. serial

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, processing-efficiency

Currently, I am reading over a study a guide that my professor handed out in class. The study guide is not an assignment, just something to know what to expect on an exam. I've completed all but 1 problem and was hoping someone could help me out.

Here is the question:
Suppose Tserial = n and Tparallel = n/p + log2(p), where times are in miliseconds and p is the 
number of processes. If we increase p by a factor of k, find a formula for how much we’ll need to increase n in order to maintain constant efficiency. How much should we increase n by if we double the number of processes from 8 to 16? Is the parallel program scalable?

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for a new value of n, call it m.  Then n/p + log2(p) = m/(kp) + log2(kp).  Solve for m.  The only nontrivial step is the identity log(ab) = log(a) + log(b).

Answer (score 14):

Both the comment and the first answer help you solve for constant parallel compute time, but that's a little different than solving for constant efficiency.

As noted above, parallel efficiency is defined by how effectively you're making use of your multiple processors.  100% efficiency would mean that you're getting a factor of p speedup from using p processors; so efficiency is defined in terms of speedup per processor:

[image]

So now you want to consider constant efficiency if you're increasing the number of processors by a factor k and the problem size by a factor k'.

Let's first do this without the "parallel overhead" term involving log(p):

[image]

Eg, efficiency is always 1, so you don't need to do anything to problem size as you vary processor number.

But because there is some overhead, for constant efficiency you need to tackle larger problem sizes as you scale up.  With the overhead term, you get
[image]

Let's look at the asymptotics here -- if you're already at an infinite number of processors, you're already at zero efficiency (because there's zero work per processor but an infinite overhead), so you can keep problem size constant; efficiency will stay the same.  On the other hand, you're never going to be able to increase the problem size enough to regain the parallel efficiency you had at p=1; that was 100% and anything you do will necessarily have less than that because of the overhead.

Also note that the amount you have to increase the problem size is always going to be at least a little bit more than the factor by which you increase the number of processors.

In the particular case you're looking at, p=8, k=2, and you need to increase your problem size by 2+2/3.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that this working is correct.

For example, if Tserial = 10ms, in an ideal world (with 100% efficiency) if you do parallel processing with 2 processes, Tparallel (ideal) is 10ms/2 = 5ms

Unfortunately, any parallel processing will incur processing overhead to manage the works which are distributed among the processors.

In this case, the formula for the time taken to manage the overhead is log2(p).
Thus, if you have 2 processors and Tserial = 10ms, the Tparallel becomes 5ms + log2(2) = 6ms

Using the example above, let's assume that 'constant efficiency' means that if we increase p by a factor of k, how much that we need to increase Tserial i.e. n so that the Tparallel is still 6ms

let a = factor to increase n

n/p + log2(p) = na/pk + log2(pk)

n/p + log2(p) = na/pk + log2(p) + log2(k)

n/p = na/pk + log2(k)

nk - na = pk log2(k)

k-a = (pk log2(k)) / n

a = k - [(pk log2(k)) / n]

if p =8 and k = 2

a = 2 - [(16 log2(2)) / n]
a = 2 - (16/n)

In this case, the parallel program is scalable as it can handle almost double the workload if the number of processor is doubled.
Provided n >> 16