# Too big efficiency - parallel computing

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

**This is only theoretical question**

In parallel computing is it possible to acheive efficiency greater than 100%?

E.g 125% efficiency

```
+-------------+------+
| Processors  | Time |
+-------------+------+
|          1  | 10s  |
|          2  | 4s   |
+-------------+------+
```

I don't mean situtations when parallel environment is configured wrong or there is some bug in code.

Efficiency definition:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13211093/2265932

[image]

Comment: How did you run the tests, what did you measure, did you do a warmup before each test, ... More details are required.

Comment: I believe OP wants to say this: it takes `10 sec` for a single CPU to do a specific task. When two CPUs are used for the same task, is it possible that in some cases the total time will be less than `10 / 2 = 5 sec`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, it is called `superlinear speedup` and it is caused usually by improving the cache usage. Though it is usually less than 125%.

See, for example, [Where does super-linear speedup come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332967/where-does-super-linear-speedup-come-from/4454251#4454251)